# How to extend variable life in for loop?

Tags: rust

When I compile the below code in Rust, I get the following error:

```
let row :Row = Row::new(vec_row.iter().map(|x| AnyValue::Utf8(x)).collect());
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
```

```rust
fn get_table(vec_rows: Vec<Vec<String>>) -> Result<DataFrame> {
    let mut rows = Vec::<Row>::new();
    for vec_row in vec_rows {
        let row: Row = Row::new(vec_row.iter().map(|x| AnyValue::Utf8(x)).collect());
        rows.push(row);
    }
    let df = DataFrame::from_rows(&rows).unwrap();
    Ok(df)
}
```

Comment: Did you try following the further instructions you ommited from the error message yet? See [mre] on what you should include when asking for help with debuging an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to build a set of referenced Utf8 rows from the owned strings in `vec_rows`, but in the process you're consuming the owned strings in `vec_rows`. They are dropped in your function while you're trying to return references to them.

Instead of `Utf8` (which is for use with `&str`s), you should use `Utf8Owned` (which is for use with `String`s):

```rust
let row: Row = Row::new(vec_row.into_iter().map(|x| AnyValue::Utf8Owned(x.into())).collect());
```

I also took the liberty to convert your function into one that's more idiomatic using `into_iter().map`:

```rust
fn get_table(vec_rows: Vec<Vec<String>>)-> Result<DataFrame> {
    let mut rows: Vec<_> = vec_rows.into_iter().map(|row| {
        Row::new(row.into_iter().map(|x| AnyValue::Utf8Owned(x.into())).collect())
    }).collect();
    
    let df = DataFrame::from_rows(&rows).unwrap();
    Ok(df)
}
```

[playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Apolars%20%3D%20%22*%22%0Aanyhow%20%3D%20%22*%22%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20polars%3A%3Aprelude%3A%3A*%3B%0Ause%20polars%3A%3Adatatypes%3A%3AAnyValue%3B%0Ause%20polars%3A%3Aframe%3A%3Arow%3A%3ARow%3B%0Ause%20anyhow%3A%3AResult%3B%0A%0Afn%20get_table(vec_rows%3A%20Vec%3A%3A%3CVec%3A%3A%3CString%3E%3E)-%3E%20Result%3CDataFrame%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20rows%20%3D%20Vec%3A%3A%3CRow%3E%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20vec_row%20in%20vec_rows%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20row%3A%20Row%20%3D%20Row%3A%3Anew(vec_row.into_iter().map(%7Cx%7C%20AnyValue%3A%3AUtf8Owned(x.into())).collect())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rows.push(row)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20df%20%3D%20DataFrame%3A%3Afrom_rows(%26rows).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(df)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20get_table(vec_rows%3A%20Vec%3CVec%3CString%3E%3E)-%3E%20Result%3CDataFrame%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20rows%3A%20Vec%3C_%3E%20%3D%20vec_rows.into_iter().map(%7Crow%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Row%3A%3Anew(row.into_iter().map(%7Cx%7C%20AnyValue%3A%3AUtf8Owned(x.into())).collect())%0A%20%20%20%20%7D).collect()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20df%20%3D%20DataFrame%3A%3Afrom_rows(%26rows).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(df)%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%22)%3B%0A%7D)